# how to calculate the inversion count using merge sort for a list of Int in Scala?

Tags: algorithm, scala, sorting

```
def mergeSort(xs: List[Int]): List[Int] = {
    val n = xs.length / 2
    if (n == 0) xs
    else {
        def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int]): List[Int] =
            (xs, ys) match {
            case(Nil, ys) => ys
            case(xs, Nil) => xs
            case(x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
                if (x < y) {
                    x :: merge(xs1, ys)
                }
                else {
                    y :: merge(xs, ys1)
                }
            }
        val (left, right) = xs splitAt(n)
        merge(mergeSort(left), mergeSort(right))
    }
}
```

Inversion Count for an array indicates – how far (or close) the array is from being sorted. If array is already sorted then inversion count is 0. If array is sorted in reverse order that inversion count is the maximum. 
Formally speaking, two elements a[i] and a[j] form an inversion if a[i] > a[j] and i < j

Example:
The sequence 2, 4, 1, 3, 5 has three inversions (2, 1), (4, 1), (4, 3).

So if this list（2, 4, 1, 3, 5）is passed to the function, the inversion count should be 3.

How do I add a variable to get the number?

Comment: actually I understand the code but I don't quite know how to add and update the variable.

Comment: That is not possible. None of of us even know what that "inversion count" means.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Apparently, this is the number of index pairs `(i, j)` such that `i < j` but `a(i) > a(j)`. However, it's still completely unclear what this piece of code has to do with the "inversion count".

Comment: @AndreyTyukin I am surprised that OP was talking about standard inversion. But since he knows "what inversion count is", It should be very very simple to add the code to calculate it as long as OP knows Scala.

Comment: @AndreyTyukin, as the title indicates, I'd like to use merge sort to compute the inversion count, that is, to add a variable to the code to complete that, but i am not very sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be something like will help

```
def mergeSort(xs: List[Int], cnt: Int): (List[Int], Int) = {
  val n = xs.length / 2
  if (n == 0) (xs, cnt)
  else {
    def merge(xs: List[Int], ys: List[Int], cnt: Int): (List[Int], Int) =
      (xs, ys) match {
        case(Nil, ys) => (ys, cnt)
        case(xs, Nil) => (xs, cnt)
        case(x :: xs1, y :: ys1) =>
          if (x <= y) {
            val t = merge(xs1, ys, cnt)
            (x :: t._1, t._2)
          }
          else {
            val t = merge(xs, ys1, cnt + xs.size)
            (y :: t._1, t._2)
          }
      }
    val (left, right) = xs splitAt(n)
    val leftMergeSort = mergeSort(left, cnt)
    val rightMergeSort = mergeSort(right, cnt)
    merge(leftMergeSort._1, rightMergeSort._1, leftMergeSort._2 + rightMergeSort._2)
  }
}
```

I am passing a tuple along all the function calls that's it.

I increment the value of the cnt when we find that first element of one list is less than the first element of second list. In this scenario we add list.length to the cnt. Look at the code, to get a more clear view.

Hope this helps!